# why radio button is not marking checked on true condition in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `anuglar7` app in which i have a dropdown list with radio buttton with each item. But radio button is not checked on successful condition. Here is what i have in my `component.html`

```
<ul class="status-table-ul" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
<li class="status-table-li" [ngClass]="[selectedIndex === i ? 'selected' : '' , filterOpt.label === 'All' ? 'all' : '']" *ngFor="let filterOpt of referralFilterOptions;let i = index" (click)="onFilterSelect(i,filterOpt.label)">
    <label class="container">{{filterOpt.label}}
        <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selectedFilterOption" name="radio" [value]="filterOpt.label" [checked]="i === selectedIndex">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
 </li>
</ul>
```

And in my `component.ts` i have like this

```
selectedIndex : number = 0;


onFilterSelect(index : number,opt : string){
    this.selectedIndex = index;
    this.refLinkArr = opt === 'All' ? this.masterRefLinkArr : this.masterRefLinkArr.filter(item => item.link_status === opt)
    $("ul.status-table-ul").removeClass("show-menu");
```

Problem is that on component load first element's radio should be checked. But it's not checked on page load. 
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this :

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedFilterOption"
```

When you use `[(ngModel)]="selectedFilterOption"`  and `[checked]="i === selectedIndex"` at the same time then the checked state depends on the [(ngModel)]

if the value of **selectedFilterOption** is 1 it will check it but 0 means false.